# mssql CONTAINTS return invalid row

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a mssql table like below:-

[image: tblstatusjadual structure]

And mssql query from php page like below:-

```
SELECT * from tblstatusjadual where (idjadual LIKE '1%' AND 
CONTAINS(idjadual,'1.1 OR 1.2 OR 1.3 OR 1.4 OR 1.5 OR 1.6 OR 1.7 OR 1.8 OR 1.9'))
and tahun='2011'
```

As you can see, the **CONTAINS** bracket no **1.10** value, but when I run this query it return result with idjadual 1.10. Why this happen?

[image: mssql query result]

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably because it's doing a floating point compare, so 1.10 == 1.1. If 'idjadual' is a char column of some sort maybe you should put quotes around the comparisons.

Comment: @PeterJ where should I put the quotes?

Comment: '1.1' OR '1.2' OR '1.3' etc but I've never used contains for that - try (idjadual = '1.1' OR idjadual = '1.2') etc

Comment: Tq peter.Yes, it works as I need. But I also want to know how to use CONTAINS in my case?

Comment: Not having used contains I'd missed it but '1.10' does contain '1.1' so the result above looks OK for a string contains as well. If you don't want 1.10 included then contains won't give you the result you're after, so either use the above or take a look at IN.

Comment: Ok. tq peter. I edit all my query to use = instead of CONTAINS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "Mountain" OR "Road" ')
GO
```

Based on this you might try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
from tblstatusjadual  
where (idjadual LIKE '1%' AND 
CONTAINS(idjadual,'"1.1" OR "1.2" OR "1.3" OR "1.4" OR "1.5" OR "1.6" OR "1.7" OR "1.8" OR "1.9"'))
and tahun='2011'
```

Comment: Your solution still does not change anything. Your query return result same as my query.